# "What about X?", one more meaning

Tags: phrase-requests, spoken-language, casual

In English I can say "what about X?" to mean "why did you mention X?", "what were you going to say about X?", "what does it have to do with X?" and so on.

How can I ask the same thing in japanese? In particular, in casual speach.

Note that this is not what I'm asking about:  "I like sushi. **How about** you?"

My question about this: for example, we're walking with my friend and suddenly she yells "sushi!". And then she says nothing. Strange. I  don't get her and ask her "Sushi? **What about** sushi"?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I get what you're asking...

Comment: Something like Xがどうした？ not an overly polite way, and not fitting every context, but that's the problem of the question not being specific enough.

Comment: @ajsmart, updated.

Comment: @macraf, updated

Comment: what about "すしだって？”

Comment: @Locksleyu, why are you asking me?

Comment: I'm not asking, I'm answering your question. Notice that "?" is in quotes => "sushi datte?"

Comment: @Locksleyu, but you said "what about".

Comment: Sorry if my comment was confusing. I just meant to suggest the phrase "sushi datte?". Though Tam san's suggestions are probably better, I personally have used the "~ datte" form before effectively for a similar purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the words you want are "すしがどうした!", "なんですし?", "すしが何!". I think there are many ways to say this.

Comment: what are other ways?

Comment: For example, すしがなんだよ!、すしがどうかしたの?, すしがなんなの! and so on.